# Adicionar propriedade em relação N-N

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Como adicionar propriedades (colunas) numa relação N-N usando EF?

Por exemplo, eu tenho a classe `Produto`:

```
public class Produto
{
    [Key]
    public int ProdutoID { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Venda> Vendas { get; set; }

    public Produto()
    {
        this.Vendas = new List<Venda>();
    }
}
```

E tenho a classe `Venda`:

```
public class Venda
{
    [Key]
    public int VendaID { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }

    public Venda()
    {
        this.Produtos = new List<Produto>();
    }
}
```

Estou usando *Code First* e por isso o EF cria automaticamente uma tabela `VendaProdutos`, o problema é que essa tabela deveria ter mais campos, como `Quantidade`, etc.

Existe alguma forma que eu possa fazer isso sem fugir do Code First ou terei que procurar outra forma de fazer o mapeamento das minhas classes (Fluent API por exemplo)?

Comment: Você terá que criar uma nova classe que ficará entre o seu relacionamento pra poder ter uma propriedade nova.

Comment: Então eu teria que trocar essas relações N-N para relações 1-N né. Não tinha pensado nisso.

Comment: Exatamente, no caso teria uma classe `ProdutoVenda` no meio.

Comment: Relações `NxM` são feitas de forma a ter uma tabela intermediária que recebe uma relação `1xN` de cada uma das outras tabelas envolvidas. Nesse caso em específico, a tabela intermediária (`ProdutoVenda`) deve ter uma chave composta pelo par das chaves das duas tabelas externas. E uma vez que esta intermediária for receber uma entrada, deve-se ter certeza que a quantidade vendida não excede o estoque...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creio que a única solução seja criar uma classe para o relacionamento.

No seu caso, ficaria da seguinte forma:

**Classe Produto**

```
public class Produto
{
    [Key]
    public int ProdutoID { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProdutoVenda> ProdutosVenda { get; set; }

}
```

**Classe Venda**

```
    public class Venda
    {
        [Key]
        public int VendaID { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public decimal Total { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ProdutoVenda> ProdutosVenda { get; set; }

    }
```

**Classe ProdutoVenda**

```
public class ProdutoVenda
{
    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
    public int VendaID { get; set; }

    public virtual Produto Produto { get; set; }
    public virtual Venda Venda { get; set; }

    public int Quantidade { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Aqueles construtores em `Produto` e `Venda` não são mais necessários. Você pode removê-los da resposta. Os outros elementos `virtual` o Entity Framework se encarrega de preencher.

Comment: @cigano, valeu! Tinha esquecido desse detalhe quando copiei ;)