# Mapear Many to Many no Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou com um problema no mapeamento com o Entity Framework.

Tenho dois models, "projeto" e "empresa", aonde na "empresa" pode haver vários "projetos".

```
 public class Projeto
 {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public byte[] Versao { get; set; }
 }


public class Empresa
{
    [Key]
    public Int32   Id                              { get;set; }  
    public String  Nome                            { get;set; } 
    public String  Fone                            { get;set; } 
    public String  Contato                         { get;set; } 
    public String  Email                           { get;set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<Projeto>  Projetos  { get;set; } 
}
```

Quando, executo no `Package Manager Console` do visual studio `Add-Migration`, para ele criar o arquivo de migration do banco, ele gera uma coluna na tabela de projetos, para referenciar a empresa.

Então visto isto, e [esta resposta aqui no So-PT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100615/44744) criei outra classe para fazer um mapeamento many-to-many

```
public class EmpresaProjeto
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Empresa Empresa {get;set;}
    public virtual Projeto Projeto { get; set; }
}
```

E registro o tipo da classe no context

```
public DbSet<Projeto> Projeto { get; set; }
public DbSet<Empresa> Empresa { get; set; }
public DbSet<EmpresaProjeto> EmpresaProjeto { get; set; }
```

Mas acontece que agora na minha "Empresa", "Projetos" sempre fica vazio, como posso fazer para que na minha entidade já traga os "Projetos" juntos?

Alguém com mais experiência no EF poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Relacionada: [Adicionar propriedade em relação N-N](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54045/18246)

Comment: Apesar de você ter falado em `N:M`, me parece que você precisa de um relacionamento `1:N`, então eu lhe pergunto, um Projeto pode ter múltiplas Empresas ou apenas 1?

Comment: @TobiasMesquita , é isso mesmo 1:N, mas como não consegui fazer funcionar, e com base nas respostas que encontrei, alterei para N:N o relacionamento para testar uma solução.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pela descrição da sua pergunta, me parece que você quer montar um relacionamento de `1:N`, onde uma `Empresa` pode ter `N` `Projeto`s e um `Projeto` pode ter apenas `1` `Empresa`, então você poderia ter o seguinte mapeamento.:

```
public class Projeto
{
    [Key]
    public int ProjetoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public byte[] Versao { get; set; }
    public int EmpresaId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EmpresaId")]
    public virtual Empresa Empresa { get;set; } 
}


public class Empresa
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 EmpresaId { get;set; }  
    public String Nome { get;set; } 
    public String Fone { get;set; } 
    public String Contato { get;set; } 
    public String Email { get;set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<Projeto>  Projetos  { get;set; } 
}
```

você pode omitir a coluna `EmpresaId` no `Projeto` da seguinte forma, porem eu não recomendo.

```
public class Projeto
{
    [Key]
    public int ProjetoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public byte[] Versao { get; set; }
    public virtual Empresa Empresa { get;set; } 
}


public class Empresa
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 EmpresaId { get;set; }  
    public String Nome { get;set; } 
    public String Fone { get;set; } 
    public String Contato { get;set; } 
    public String Email { get;set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<Projeto>  Projetos  { get;set; } 
}
```

Não recomendo pelo seguinte fato: caso você tenha o `EmpresaId` da `Empresa` e queira atualizar o `Projeto`, você terá de carregar a `Empresa` no `Contexto`, seja com um `Attach` de um objeto incompleto ou buscando com um `Find`.

```
// Attach do objeto incompleto
var empresa = new Empresa { EmpresaId = empresaId };
context.Empresas.Attach(empresa); 
context.Entry(empresa).State = EntityState.Unchanged; 

projeto.Empresa = empresa;
context.SaveChanges();

// Consultar Objeto
var empresa = context.Empresas.Find(empresaId); 
projeto.Empresa = empresa;
context.SaveChanges();

// Setar o EmpresaId no Projeto
projeto.EmpresaId = empresaId;
context.SaveChanges();
```

mas se realmente precisa de um relacionamento de `N:M`, você não é forçado a criar uma Entidade extra.

```
public class Projeto
{
    [Key]
    public int ProjetoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public byte[] Versao { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Empresa> Empresas { get;set; } 
}

public class Empresa
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 EmpresaId { get;set; }  
    public String Nome { get;set; } 
    public String Fone { get;set; } 
    public String Contato { get;set; } 
    public String Email { get;set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<Projeto> Projetos { get;set; } 
}
```

No exemplo acima, o EF irá criar a tabela `ProjetoEmpresa` no Banco de Dados, tendo uma chave composta com `ProjetoId` e `EmpresaId`.

Porém caso a ligação entre `Projeto` e `Empresa` adicione alguma informação entra, como por exemplo o numero do Contrato, neste caso é interpresante adicionar uma nova entidade.

```
public class Projeto
{
    [Key]
    public int ProjetoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public byte[] Versao { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProjetoEmpresa> Empresas { get;set; } 
}

public class Empresa
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 EmpresaId { get;set; }  
    public String Nome { get;set; } 
    public String Fone { get;set; } 
    public String Contato { get;set; } 
    public String Email { get;set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<ProjetoEmpresa> Projetos { get;set; } 
}

public class ProjetoEmpresa
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ProjetoId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int EmpresaId { get; set; }
    public string Contrato { get; set; }        

    [ForeignKey("ProjetoId")]
    public virtual Projeto Projeto { get;set; }     
    [ForeignKey("EmpresaId")]
    public virtual Empresa Empresa { get;set; } 
}
```

novamente, você pode vir a omitir os campos `EmpresaId` e `ProjetoId` no `ProjetoEmpresa`, mas não recomendo.

Por fim, não vejo ganho em ter uma `Chave Simples Auto Incremental` na tabela `ProjetoEmpresa`, lembre-se, ele normalmente será utilizada apenas como uma ponte entre `Projeto` e `Empresa` então é interessante ter uma chave composta que reforce esta integridade.

Se optar por ter uma `Chave Simples Auto Incremental`, não esqueça de criar um `Índice Único` como sugerido pelo @CiganoMorrisonMendez.

Answer (score 4):

Olá,

Na sua classe de mapeamento tente especificar as propriedades que serão as foreign keys:

- Estas propriedades devem manter o tipo e a nomenclatura do objeto pai.

  ```
  public class EmpresaProjeto
  {
      [Key]
      public Int32 Id { get; set; }
      public int EmpresaId {get;set;}
      public virtual Empresa Empresa {get;set;}
      public int ProjetoId { get; set; }
      public virtual Projeto Projeto { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Ou utilizar Data Annotations:

  ```
  public class EmpresaProjeto
  {
     [Key]
     public Int32 Id { get; set; }
     [ForeignKey("EmpresaId")]
     public virtual Empresa Empresa {get;set;}
     [ForeignKey("ProjetoId")]
     public virtual Projeto Projeto { get; set; }
  }
  ```

Acredito que possa resolver.

Answer (score 2):

Faltam algumas coisas:

```
public class EmpresaProjeto
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    [Index("IUQ_EmpresaProjeto_EmpresaId_ProjetoId", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
    public int EmpresaId { get; set; }
    [Index("IUQ_EmpresaProjeto_EmpresaId_ProjetoId", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
    public int ProjetoId { get; set; }

    public virtual Empresa Empresa {get;set;}
    public virtual Projeto Projeto { get; set; }
}
```

Faltou também as relações inversas:

```
 public class Projeto
 {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public byte[] Versao { get; set; }

    // Faltou
    public virtual ICollection<EmpresaProjeto> ProjetoEmpresas { get; set; }
 }


public class Empresa
{
    [Key]
    public Int32   Id                              { get;set; }  
    public String  Nome                            { get;set; } 
    public String  Fone                            { get;set; } 
    public String  Contato                         { get;set; } 
    public String  Email                           { get;set; } 
    // Não é mais 1:N, então essa propriedade sai.
    // public virtual ICollection<Projeto>  Projetos  { get;set; } 

    // Entra esta no lugar.
    public virtual ICollection<EmpresaProjeto> EmpresaProjetos { get; set; }
}
```